# css 3 column grid applying equal margin

Tags: html, css

```css
.num_pad_wrap {
    width:300px;
    background:#eee;
    height:300px;
}
.num_pad_wrap div {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    background: #666C77;
    height: 50px;
    margin:1%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="num_pad_wrap">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>0</div>
    <div>C</div>
    
</div>
```

I'm trying to do a calculator. As you can see I failed to calculate the margin to fit well in the container. It's easy if I can just hardcode the pixel but in my case I have to do percentage. How to style the margin equally for all sides?

Comment: If you want the same margin for all sides of the calculatr try setting margin in .num_pad_wrap...And replace px with % in height and width.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.num_pad_wrap {
    width: 300px;
    background:#eee;
    height:300px;
}

.num_pad_wrap .row {
    margin-left: 2%;
}
.num_pad_wrap .row div {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    background: #666C77;
    height: 50px;
    margin:1%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="num_pad_wrap">
    <div class="row">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div>7</div>
        <div>8</div>
        <div>9</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div>0</div>
        <div>C</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Since your 3 buttons take up 96% of the width, (32% * 3), your total margins left is 4%.

You can wrap each row around a `row` class, then set margin-left to half of your total margin, which is `2%` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pgey5cmc/1/)**

```
 .num_pad_wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    width:300px;
    background:#eee;
    height:auto;
    padding:1.2% 1.2% 0% 1.2%;
}
.num_pad_wrap div {
    background: #eee;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 3.2%;
    margin-bottom: 3.2%;
    background: #666C77;
    height: 50px;
    width: 31.2%;
    margin-bottom: 3.2%;
}
/* clear col */
 .num_pad_wrap div:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
    margin-left: 0;
    clear: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="num_pad_wrap">
    <div>1</div>
     ........
    <div>C</div>
</div>
```